# Javascript library for convert .ini file to .json file (client side)

Tags: javascript, json, converters, ini

I'm trying to find a JS library, for coverting .ini file to .json file

I need that all oparations will be in client-side(!!!), so https://www.npmjs.org/package/clonkrefiniparser is not helping me.

For example:

.ini file:

```
[Master_Settings:1]
Model Name=RC-74DL
IP Address=192.168.1.39
Port=50000
[Device_Ports:1]
[Slave_Settings:2]
ConfigurationfilePath=C:\Users\name\Documents\K-Cssig2\Devices\RC-63D.xml
Button Label1=
[Device_Ports:2]
ADIO Mode 1 = DI
ADIO Mode 2 = DI
[Slave_Settings:11]
Model Name = Test 3
Desription=
ConfigurationfilePath=Devices\Test 3.xml
Button Label1=
Button Label2=
[Device_Ports:11]
ADIO Mode 1 = DI
ADIO Mode 2 = DI

[Serial:1:6]
Main Display=True
Default Port Description=MX660
User Port Description=MX660
Driver Name=BenQ MX660 A
Device_On_Command=N/A
Device_Off_Command=N/A
IsPowerQuery=False
IsLampQuery=False
```

To .json format

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the .ini file stored locally too?

Comment: Yes exactly, (but it's possible to bring the file from the server). My point is that all the conversion will be in the cliet side.

Comment: Isn't this just a simple string manipulation task?

Comment: Yes, but if there's a library that do the job, why to work so hard...

Comment: Just to learn something ; ). Notice, that searching for libraries or other off-site resources is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indeed is just string manipulation and you don't really need a *library* for it.

Here's a suggestion (ES6 snippet, the inifile is within a hidden div in html):

```js
( () => {
    let ini2Obj = {};
    const keyValuePair = kvStr => {
     const kvPair = kvStr.split('=').map( val => val.trim() );
        return { key: kvPair[0], value: kvPair[1] };
    };
    const result = document.querySelector("#results");
    document.querySelector( '#inifile' ).textContent
     .split( /\n/ )                                       // split lines
        .map( line => line.replace( /^\s+|\r/g, "" ) )     // cleanup whitespace
        .forEach( line =>  {                               // convert to object
            line = line.trim();
            if ( line.startsWith('#') || line.startsWith(';') ) { return false; }
            if ( line.length ) {
              if ( /^\[/.test(line) ) {
                this.currentKey = line.replace(/\[|\]/g,'');
                ini2Obj[this.currentKey] = {};
              } else if ( this.currentKey.length ) {
                const kvPair = keyValuePair(line);
                ini2Obj[this.currentKey][kvPair.key] = kvPair.value;
              }
            } 
          }, {currentKey: ''} );
    
    result.textContent += 
     `**Check: ini2Obj['Slave_Settings:11'].ConfigurationfilePath = ${
          ini2Obj['Slave_Settings:11'].ConfigurationfilePath}`;
    
    result.textContent += 
      `\n\n**The converted object (JSON-stringified)\n${
      JSON.stringify(ini2Obj, null, ' ')}`;
})();
```

```css
.hidden {display: none}
```

```html
<div class="hidden" id="inifile">
    # this is a comment line
    [Master_Settings:1]
    Model Name=RC-74DL
    IP Address=192.168.1.39
    Port=50000
    
    [Device_Ports:1]
    
    [Slave_Settings:2]
    ConfigurationfilePath=C:\Users\name\Documents\K-Cssig2\Devices\RC-63D.xml
    Button Label1=
    
    ; this is a comment line too
    [Device_Ports:2]
    ADIO Mode 1 = DI
    ADIO Mode 2 = DI
    
    [Slave_Settings:11]
    Model Name = Test 3
    Desription=
    ConfigurationfilePath=Devices\Test 3.xml
    # Note: no labels here
    Button Label1=
    Button Label2=
    
    [Device_Ports:11]
    ADIO Mode 1 = DI
    ADIO Mode 2 = DI
    
    [Serial:1:6]
    Main Display=True
    Default Port Description=MX660
    User Port Description=MX660
  
    # Note: empty lines are ok
    Driver Name=BenQ MX660 A
    Device_On_Command=N/A
    Device_Off_Command=N/A
    IsPowerQuery=False
    IsLampQuery=False
</div>

<pre id="results"></pre>
```

See it in action in [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/e9wrbhqs/embedded/result%2Cjs%2Chtml/)

Comment: @Kooilnc can you please fix a typo in your answer from `,currrentBlock` to `,currentBlock`

Comment: Sure, but no need for it anymore: updated code to snippet using ES6

Comment: Nice solution, but comments in INI files usually start with `;` and not with `#`. See [this Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Comments). (It says that some programs use `#` so maybe consider adding support for both)