# .dat (unknown notation) to json format

Tags: json, parsing

I am working in an open-source game called Argentum Online, you can check out our code here https://github.com/ao-libre

The problem I am facing is it has a lot of files with the extension `.dat` with this format:

```
[NPC12] 
Name=Sastre
Desc=¡Hola forastero! Soy el Sastre de Ullathorpe, Bienvenido!
Head=9
Body=50
Heading=3
Movement=1
Attackable=0
Comercia=1
TipoItems=3
Hostil=0
GiveEXP=0
GiveGLD=0
InvReSpawn=0
NpcType=0
Alineacion=0
DEF=0
MaxHit=0
MaxHp=0

[NPC19]
Name=Sastre
Desc=¡Bienvenida Viajera! Tengo hermosas vestimentas para ofrecerte...
Head=70
Body=80
Heading=3
Movement=1
Attackable=0
Comercia=1
TipoItems=3
Hostil=0
GiveEXP=0
GiveGLD=0
```

I would like to know if this kind of parsing has a proper name and what is a good way to convert it to json?

Comment: This looks like an INI file.

Comment: after see this I think so too, thanks @mx0
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

Comment: "what is a good way to convert it to json?"...by writing some code and/or searching online in case anyone has already written code to do that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

After read the comment above from @mx0. 
The format is called INI Format
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

Here an answer for the transformation between INI to JSON

Npm Module:
https://github.com/npm/ini

Or 
ES6 Snippet

```
let ini2Obj = {};
const keyValuePair = kvStr => {
    const kvPair = kvStr.split('=').map( val => val.trim() );
    return { key: kvPair[0], value: kvPair[1] };
};
const result = document.querySelector("#results");
document.querySelector( '#inifile' ).textContent
    .split( /\n/ )                                       // split lines
    .map( line => line.replace( /^\s+|\r/g, "" ) )     // cleanup whitespace
    .forEach( line =>  {                               // convert to object
        line = line.trim();
        if ( line.startsWith('#') || line.startsWith(';') ) { return false; }
        if ( line.length ) {
          if ( /^\[/.test(line) ) {
            this.currentKey = line.replace(/\[|\]/g,'');
            ini2Obj[this.currentKey] = {};
          } else if ( this.currentKey.length ) {
            const kvPair = keyValuePair(line);
            ini2Obj[this.currentKey][kvPair.key] = kvPair.value;
          }
        } 
      }, {currentKey: ''} );

result.textContent += 
    `**Check: ini2Obj['Slave_Settings:11'].ConfigurationfilePath = ${
      ini2Obj['Slave_Settings:11'].ConfigurationfilePath}`;

result.textContent += 
  `\n\n**The converted object (JSON-stringified)\n${
  JSON.stringify(ini2Obj, null, ' ')}`;
```

Original answer:
[Javascript library for convert .ini file to .json file (client side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450359/javascript-library-for-convert-ini-file-to-json-file-client-side)